# R: error on estimating mle with MaxLik() package

Tags: r, glm, mle

My purpose is to find maximum likelihood estimator using Newton Raphson algorithm and compare the solution with glm(). so I tried to use maxLik() in R. And it turns out error, I have not use this package before, please fix this error, thank you!!

```
d <- read.delim("http://dnett.github.io/S510/Disease.txt")
    
d$disease=as.factor(d$disease)
d$ses=as.factor(d$ses)
d$sector=as.factor(d$sector)
str(d)

y<-as.numeric(as.character(d$disease))
x1<-as.numeric(as.character(d$age))
x2<-as.numeric(as.character(d$sector))
x3<-as.numeric(as.character(d$ses))

oreduced <- glm(disease ~ age + sector, family=binomial(link = logit), data=d)
summary(oreduced)
    
    
nlldbin=function(param){
  eta<-param[1]+param[2]*x1+param[3]*(x2==2)
  p<-1/(1+exp(-eta))
  -sum(y*log(p)+(1-y)*log(1-p),na.rm=TRUE)
}
est_nr<-maxLik(nlldbin,start=c(0.01,0.01,0.01))
summary(est_nr)
```

The result is

```
Iteration 1 
Parameter:
[1]   9841290 377928533   4325584
Gradient (first 30 components):
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  NaN  NaN  NaN
Error in maxNRCompute(fn = function (theta, fnOrig, gradOrig = NULL, hessOrig = NULL,  : 
  NA in gradient
```

Comment: Does `nlldbin` have NA? It seems `x3` is unused? Have you walked through the `maxLik()` documentation example and does that work? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/maxLik/versions/1.4-8/topics/maxLik

Comment: the example does work, but when I apply the package to the model, it wont work

Comment: I can't see why this doesn't work. Your function works in `optim(c(0,0,0), nlldbin)` . I tried changing the loss to `-sum(dbinom(y, 1, p, log=TRUE))` in case there was a stability issue but same error.

Comment: ...argh remove the negative from the LL !

Comment: I have tried using optim package and it works. but in this case I want to compare the estimation with maxLik package where I can use newton-raphson algorithm to find the estimation. Do you have any idea to fix this?

Comment: yes, my second comment (which may have been unclear ); use `sum(y*log(p)+(1-y)*log(1-p))` or `sum(dbinom(y, 1, p, log=TRUE))` i.e. no negative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are trying to maximise the log-likelihood, but due to the negative applied to the sum, your function is minimising. Therefore just remove the negative, giving:

```
nlldbin <- function(param){
  eta <- param[1] + param[2]*x1 + param[3]*(x2==2)
  p <- 1/(1+exp(-eta))  
  sum(y*log(p) + (1-y) * log(1-p), na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

This is different from other optimisers, like `optim`, which often minimise by default. Which is why you would negate the sum, as you did.

ps you could write your function using in built functions, which may be a bit more stable (and less typing):

```
nlldbin2 <- function(param){
  eta <- cbind(1, x1, x2 == 2) %*% param
  p <- plogis(eta)
  sum(dbinom(y, 1, p, log=TRUE))
}
```